# How to hide form when sending on the same page?

Tags: php

> The development of this form is to send the data on the same page.

I want to hide the contact form when sending and displaying a message for example: **thanks for contacting us.**

The problem I present is that when you perform the send action the form, is hidden and displays the error messages but the contact form remains hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact US</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
$errors = '';
$nombre = '';
$email = '';
$telefono = '';
$mensaje = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if($_SESSION['vcode'] != $_POST['vcode']) {
    $errors .= "The characters do not match the captcha code";
  }

  $nombre = $_POST["name"];
  $email    = $_POST["mail"];
  $telefono = $_POST["phone"];
  $mensaje  = $_POST["message"];

  if(empty($nombre)) {
    $errors .= "\n Please enter your name. "; 
  }else {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nombre)) {
      $errors .= "\n Only letters and spaces are allowed.";
    }
  }
  if(empty($email)) {
    $errors .= "\n Please enter your email. "; 
  }else{
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errors .="\n Invalid email";
    }
  }
  if(empty($telefono)) {
    $errors .= "\n Please enter your phone number. "; 
  }else{
    if(!preg_match("/^\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$/", $telefono)) {
      $errors .="\n Invalid number";
    }
  }
  if($_POST['producto'] == 0){
     $errors .= "\n You must select a product";
  }
  if(empty($mensaje)) {
    $errors .= "\n Please enter your message. "; 
  }
  if(empty($errors)) {
    $asunto = "";
    $message = "Usuario:".$_POST['name']." Email:".$_POST['mail']." Telefono ".$_POST['phone']." Informacion ".$_POST['message'];
    $destino = "contacto@example.com";
    $remitente = "From: contacto@example.com";
    mail($destino,$asunto,$message,$remitente);
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    echo "Thanks for your comments";
  }
}
?>

<div class="error">
<?php
if(!empty($errors)){
  echo "<p class='err'>".nl2br($errors)."</p>";
}else{
?>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="touch">
    <div class="name">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value='<?php echo htmlentities($nombre) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <input type="text" name="mail"  placeholder="Email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($email) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="phone">
      <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value='<?php echo htmlentities($telefono) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="select-pro">
      <select name="producto">
        <option value="0" selected>Affair...</option>
        <option value="1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="2">Product 2<option>
        <option value="3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="4">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="Customer-message">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Su consulta..."><?php echo htmlentities($mensaje) ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="capcha">
      <img src="image.php" name="vcode" id="phoca-captcha"/>
      <input name="vcode" type="text" placeholder="Codigo captcha">
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *I want to hide the form when sending and displaying this message* dynamically decides when to print the form or print the *thank you* message?

Comment: Since you have a `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ...}`, then just wrap the `<form>` html code in an `else { ... }` block and it will not show the form after it has been submitted.

Comment: ...or use ajax/js.

Comment: yes, just echo the message you want and add an exit right under it

Comment: Then you could do `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $errors = ''; ) { ... your form ... }`

Comment: set $errors .= "\n Thanks Message.";  and check if else condition, if it's true show the message that's it.

Comment: Try this $msg='thanks for contacting us.';  <?PHP if(isset($msg)){ echo $msg } else { // form HTML }

Comment: @Fred-ii- My question already has an answer that solved my problem, it is necessary to close my question? I think it should be opened even more when there is an answer that solved the problem and would also serve for other users who may present a similar problem.

Comment: @coatless My question already has an answer that solved my problem, it is necessary to close my question? I think it should be opened even more when there is an answer that solved the problem and would also serve for other users who may present a similar problem.

Comment: @Mufaddal My question already has an answer that solved my problem, it is necessary to close my question? I think it should be opened even more when there is an answer that solved the problem and would also serve for other users who may present a similar problem.

Comment: @SZenC My question already has an answer that solved my problem, it is necessary to close my question? I think it should be opened even more when there is an answer that solved the problem and would also serve for other users who may present a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Your Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact US</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
@session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if($_SESSION['vcode'] != $_POST['vcode']) {
    $errors = "The characters do not match the captcha code";
  }

  $nombre = $_POST["name"];
  $email    = $_POST["mail"];
  $telefono = $_POST["phone"];
  $mensaje  = $_POST["message"];
    $asunto = "";
    $message = "Usuario:".$_POST['name']." Email:".$_POST['mail']." Telefono ".$_POST['phone']." Informacion ".$_POST['message'];
    $destino = "contacto@example.com";
    $remitente = "From: contacto@example.com";
    mail($destino,$asunto,$message,$remitente);
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    $msg= "Thanks for your comments";
}
?>
<div class="error">
<?php
if(isset($msg)){
  echo "<p class='err'>".$msg."</p>";
}else{
    if(isset($errors) echo $errors;
?>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="touch">
    <div class="name">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value='' oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your name.')" required>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <input type="email" name="mail"  placeholder="Email" value='' title="Please enter your email."  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your email.')" required>
    </div>
    <div class="phone">
      <input type="tel" name="phone" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Please enter your phone number." oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your phone number.')" placeholder="Phone" value='' required>
    </div>
    <div class="select-pro">
      <select name="producto" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Select a product.')"  required>
        <option value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="0">Affair...</option>
        <option value="1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="2">Product 2<option>
        <option value="3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="4">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="Customer-message">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" title="Please enter your message." placeholder="Su consulta..." oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your message.')"  required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="capcha">
      <img src="image.php" name="vcode" id="phoca-captcha"/>
      <input name="vcode" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter captcha.')"  type="text" placeholder="Codigo captcha">
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Regrads :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  //ur php code (allways use ) $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
}else{
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="touch">
    <div class="name">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value='<?php echo htmlentities($nombre) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <input type="text" name="mail"  placeholder="Email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($email) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="phone">
      <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value='<?php echo htmlentities($telefono) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="select-pro">
      <select name="producto">
        <option value="0" selected>Affair...</option>
        <option value="1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="2">Product 2<option>
        <option value="3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="4">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="Customer-message">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Su consulta..."><?php echo htmlentities($mensaje) ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="capcha">
      <img src="image.php" name="vcode" id="phoca-captcha"/>
      <input name="vcode" type="text" placeholder="Codigo captcha">
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<div class="error">
<?php
if(!empty($errors)){
  echo "<p class='err'>".nl2br($errors)."</p>";
?>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="touch">
    <div class="name">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value='<?php echo htmlentities($nombre) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <input type="text" name="mail"  placeholder="Email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($email) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="phone">
      <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value='<?php echo htmlentities($telefono) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="select-pro">
      <select name="producto">
        <option value="0" selected>Affair...</option>
        <option value="1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="2">Product 2<option>
        <option value="3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="4">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="Customer-message">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Su consulta..."><?php echo htmlentities($mensaje) ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="capcha">
      <img src="image.php" name="vcode" id="phoca-captcha"/>
      <input name="vcode" type="text" placeholder="Codigo captcha">
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
<?php
}
else
{
?>

<p>thanks for contacting us.</p>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I do not understand how I have to structure the **PHP** code and the **HTML** form in the example that you have indicated to me.

Comment: just now i edited the answer.. please check.!

Comment: Hide the form without sending Friend?

Comment: if(empty($errors)) {
    $asunto = "";
    $message = "Usuario:".$_POST['name']." Email:".$_POST['mail']." Telefono ".$_POST['phone']." Informacion ".$_POST['message'];
    $destino = "contacto@example.com";
    $remitente = "From: contacto@example.com";
    mail($destino,$asunto,$message,$remitente);
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    $errors .= "\n  thanks for contacting us. "; 
  }

Comment: $errors .= "\n thanks for contacting us. "; check this condition if($errors=="thanks for contacting us.")

Comment: Still does not work the message: (thanks for contacting us.) remains active and the form has been hidden without having started the send action.